# Reading / modifying fortran file

Tags: python, regex, find

I have a big fortran (f90) file that is used to generate an input file for numerical simulations. I would like to create a GUI to set the parameters of the simulations written within the f90 file.
Right now I am trying to create a python script that can find, store and modify (if necessary) these variables (there are a lot of them).

I am trying to access values that are stored this way (this is a shortenned version) :

```
! ib  : ply orientation
!       ply at   0 : ib = 1
!       ply at  90 : ib = 2
!       ply at  45 : ib = 3
!       ply at -45 : ib = 4
a = 7500.
b = 8.
e = 579.
!--------------Centre 
x0 = 0.
y0 = 0. 
!--------------Radius 
Rfoc = 1600.
!--------------End of geometric parameters
```

So far, the code looks like this :

```
import re

geomVar = ["a =","b =","e =","Rfoc ="]

endGeom = "End of geometric parameters"

def goFetchGeom(fileNameVariable, valueInput):
    valueOutput = []

    for line in fileNameVariable.readlines():
        # Looking for svalue numbers associated with search value
        if any(string in line for string in valueInput):
            result = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', line)]
            valueOutput.append(result[0])

        # End of search loop to avoid reading the whole file
        elif endGeom in line :
            fileNameVariable.seek(0) #rewind the file
            return valueOutput

with open("mesh_Comp_UD.f90", "r+") as f:
    geomValue = goFetchGeom(f,geomVar)

print geomValue
```

**First problem:** it finds lines that have "ib = ..." within them because the variable "b =" stored in geomVar.

**Second problem:** if a line has multiple variables, I only get the first one, not all of them.

Because they are numerous, I would like to pass the variables i'm looking for, in the form of an array, directly in the function. Moreover, since the file is very long, I do not want to start a search from scratch for every variable.

Comment: First problem: Do the `a = ` lines actually start with a space? than you can also add the space to the definitions in `geomVar`.

Comment: Actually no, my bad, they start at the beginning of the line